# Flexbox - Search result popup underneath searchbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to learn how to build a textbox that is an auto-expanding sort of search box like you see on Google:

### Desired Result

---

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

### High-Level Design

---

In this design below, I demonstrate that I want it to visually seem as if the textbox itself is expanding. The way I see it, there is an input box for the text, but the height of the underlying searchbox-container is auto expanding on the y-axis.

---

[image]

### Attempt

---

```css
nav {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b1aeae;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 925px;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box {
  border: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-icon {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: "Inter";
  width: 70%;
}

.search-box input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}

.search-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 98%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: #b7b5b5;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 13px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 13px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  box-shadow: 10px 13px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.search-result:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.search-result:hover:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}

.search-result {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.search-result:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.links-container {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="search-container">
          <div class="search-box">
            <ion-icon name="search-outline" class="search-icon"></ion-icon>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search articles & videos here" />
          </div>
          <div class="search-results">
            <div class="search-result">Result 1</div>
            <div class="search-result">Result 2</div>
            <div class="search-result">Result 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="links-container"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

#### Current Outcome:

Clearly this is not looking good. I'm new to Flexbox so having some difficulty structuring this to achieve the previously mentioned goal.

[image]

Comment: You might want to look at the code snippet feature in stackoverflow. Edit your post and hit Ctrl-M, and you should see exactly what to do. That will create a snippet that everyone can run and see what the result looks like. Easier for everyone! :)

Comment: @BobRodes Cool, added, thanks!

Comment: remove `display: block` from the `search-results` class

Comment: @Hyetigran I've updated the runnable snippet above, I see mainly an issue with margin, but adding something like margin-top isn't a solution for me as it skews as the result number changes.

Comment: You may need to add JS to dynamically render the search results. Search box should contain an input. Lastly, you could use JS to grab the X and Y coords of the search box and render search results below it.

Comment: I'm trying to think in terms of just div structuring in this case, ignoring the textbox itself. I ultimately just want a dynamically resizable div that appears underneath the searchbox container. I can worry about styling it to blend later.

Comment: @Hyetigran - In other words, I want those results to just appear under the div that looks like a textbox.

Comment: Can i use javascript to search filtering?

Comment: @RayeesAC I don't actually care about that functionality - I will implement the logic later. Was just mostly interested in the format of the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had a lot of stuff that needed to change, so I pretty much rewrote it. Hopefully, I've given you some ideas to build on.

Some points:

1. `display: flex` should only be set on a flex container, not on the cell elements.
2. Use `flex-basis` if you need to set the width of a flex cell (don't use `width`).
3. Don't use margins. Use `flex-gap` to space out your cells.
4. Don't set the height unless you have to. Let the flex display try to set it for you first. In this example, we have to set the height of the link elements to keep them from being the same height as the search elements. (Short of using a grid, there's no way around that that I can see.)
5. Prefer padding to size your elements. (*Very much* prefer it over `height`.)
6. If you want something with two dimensions, don't use flex at all. Use grid. A vertical flex within a horizontal flex is beginning to push the envelope for what flex is intended for (a one-dimensional arrangement of a set of related elements); you could just as well set this up as a grid with blank areas beneath the menu.
7. As for dynamically resizing the container div, you don't have to do anything special. If you programmatically add elements to the container, flex will take care of resizing it.

Here's some code:

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    nav {
      min-width: 800px;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      column-gap: 40px;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .search-container {
      border: 2px solid darkgrey;
      border-radius: 20px;
      flex-basis: 40%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      column-gap: 20px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .search-container a, .search-container p {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .search-container p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 30px 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    }

    .search-container a:last-child {
      border: none;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    }

    .links-container {
      display: flex;
      padding: 10px 0;
      flex-basis: 40%;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .links-container a {
      height: 60px;
      padding: 20px 40px;
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }

    .links-container a:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .header-overlay {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 800px;
      height: 120px;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    <nav>
      <div class="search-container">
        <p>Search Results</p>
        <a href="#">Result 1</a>
        <a href="#">Result 2</a>
        <a href="#">Result 3</a>
        <a href="#">Result 4</a>
        <a href="#">Result 5</a>
      </div>
      <div class="links-container">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
        <a href="#">Three</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

As you can see, this code (especially the HTML) is simpler than yours. Basically, a flex is a container (with `display: flex` set) and a single set of nested elements. Any of those elements can be a container for another flex. That's what we have here: the `nav` is a flex with two elements, and each of those elements (search and links) is a flex container as well. A few observations:

1. Using `box-sizing: border-box` everywhere will make your life a lot easier. You probably have had the experience of setting up two `div`s, setting their width to 50%, and being mystified that they won't fit on one line. It's because by default, padding and borders get added onto the *outside* of the div at the specified width, so its width becomes more than 50%. What this setting does is put padding and borders *inside* the width instead of outside it.
2. Notice how to set `border-radius` for only some of the corners using `border-top-left-radius`, etc.
3. Your design appears to want to have your search results drop below the header. This is a bit difficult to do with any setting for the search results themselves. The easier way to do it is to simply "fake" it overlaying a `div` at the top. You'll see that I've set `div.header-overlay` to `position: absolute`. That positions it at the top of the screen. Then, setting the `z-index` to 1 for both the search and links elements brings them above the header overlay.
4. When you run the code here, the links take up more than 40% of the horizontal space; that's because the padding I used make it do that. I set the `min-width` to 800px so it wouldn't look too squashed, but that causes horizontal scrolling here, which isn't the best for an actual page. So, you'll want to play with `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`, as well as media queries and different layouts for different screens, to make the layout more responsive.

That should give you some missing pieces for building flex displays. You can tinker with the markup and settings and learn more.

Comment: Hey @Bob, I really appreciate this write-up. I read it over a few times this morning and definitely learned some things. Thanks so much!

Comment: My one question I have here. How can I have the search results grow, without affecting the height of what's underneath it? In other words, without pushing down whatever elements exist beneath the header.

Comment: @Ryan Yeah, that does have to be addressed. Perhaps you can implement the suggestions given, and then ask that as another question. It's easier for everyone if we treat that as a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you!

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b1aeae;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 925px;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box {
  border: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.search-results {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: #b7b5b5;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
}

.search-result {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
}

.links-container {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b1aeae;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 925px;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: top;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box {
  border: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.search-results {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: #b7b5b5;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
}

.search-result {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.links-container {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="search-container">
      <div class="search-box"></div>
      <div class="search-results">
        <div class="search-result">Result 1</div>
        <div class="search-result">Result 2</div>
        <div class="search-result">Result 3</div>
        <div class="search-result">Result 4</div>
        <div class="search-result">Result 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="links-container"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravindra. Can the textbox be center aligned on the nav?

Comment: I've updated my snippet and it's closer to what I want, but unsure if I'm doing anything too weird.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to align center of div

```
.search-container {
  align-items: top;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

instead of

```
.search-container {
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And add
`.search-results {align-items: center;}` to align center

then add to `search-result`,

```
.search-result {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

For search result add js

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("search-box");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("search-results");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

**Working demo**

```js
function searching(input) {
    input.classList.add("active");
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("search-results");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function fun(obj){
   obj.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b1aeae;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 925px;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: top;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box {
  border: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding:0 30px;
  display: flex;
  top:18px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.search-box.active{
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #b7b5b5;
  border-radius:0px;
  background:transparent;
}
.search-box.active ~ .search-results{
  visibility:visible;
}
.search-results {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 180px;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
  visibility:hidden;
  margin-top:15px;
}

.search-result {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.links-container {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="search-container">
      <input class="search-box" id="search-box" type="search"  onkeyup="searching(this)" onfocus="fun(this)" placeholder="Please search fruits..">
      <div class="search-results" id="search-results">
        <div class="search-result">Apple</div>
        <div class="search-result">Mango</div>
        <div class="search-result">Orange</div>
        <div class="search-result">Grape</div>
        <div class="search-result">Watermelon</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="links-container"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didn't use quite this, but I got close to what I'm looking for in my original snippet. I think our approaches differ slightly. Any chance you have feedback on my updates?